# In the storyboard the width of the UIViewController is not the width of the iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am trying out the new Xcode6. When I create a new project for an iPhone and I open up the storyboard, the default UIViewController is wider than the iPhone width.

Why is that so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's due to a new feature in Interface Builder, that enables designing for multiple device sizes and orientations in a single Storyboard. From the docs:

> Size classes for iOS 8 make dealing with different screen sizes and
>   orientations more flexible. You can create a single interface that
>   works on both iPad and iPhone, automatically adjusting to orientation
>   change as well. Use size classes to design a single, universal
>   storyboard, with small customizations, which adjusts to the strengths
>   of each form factor. There is no longer any need to create an
>   device-specific storyboard—instead, you target the appropriate size
>   classes and tune your interface for the best experience on each
>   device. iOS Simulator fully supports size classes as well.

When working with size classes, ViewControllers are represented with square views by default, in order to make clear that you aren't laying out the views in a specific orientation or interface size.

You can disable Size Classes on a per storyboard basis. Just uncheck the Use Size Classes option:

[image: Disabling Size Classes]

For more detail on Size Classes, refer to the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH6-SW1)

Comment: Thanks, but still not sure how to use it. I didn't notice any difference. And also when I start the emulator the button that I added in the center of the view is not displayed in the center on the emulator.